# COM unregister/register type library problem

Tags: com

I have a .NET COM DLL that I want to unregister. I do:
regasm.exe /u ConfigManager.dll

When I look with COM-ole viewer app I still see in type libraries section an entry for ConfigManager( specifies the path to ConfigManager.tlb there). How can I make sure I deregister for good any entries of ConfigManager.dll COM ?

I ask this because I have a nasty error where it seems that ConfigManager clients do not see some types from ConfigManager and want to make sure I deregister and register again ConfigManager

Comment: Regasm.exe doesn't register a type library.  Nor can it unregister one.  I could explain more but you're getting sloppy with your questions.

Comment: Thanks again for your interest Hans :-). actually the problem was solved for me by running: regasm.exe ConfigManager.dll ; regasm.exe WmConfigManager.dll /tlb. Before I didn't run /tlb option and because of that I had problems creatying types from ConfigManager

Comment: I also changed the question title to be more precise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a typelib registration utility.  TypeLibs are not specific to .NET so you can find these kinds of ones anywhere.

Here's a simple one:

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/utilities/Type_Library_Registration_Utility/VB6_Register_TypeLib_Utility.asp

I prefer to use TlbExp instead of the /tlb option of RegAsm to get a typlelib without automagically registering it.  That way I can explicitly register (or unregesiter) the typelib.

Comment: "to get a typlelib without automagically registering it", quite don't understand what you mean by that .. Doesn't this tool add the *.dll to the system as /tlb option does ? What is the difference ?

Comment: @Ghita the /tlb option both generates the typelib (.tlb file) and registers it.  Using TlbExp you can generate the typelib without registering it.  Then I use a typelib registration utility to explicitly register and unregister the typelib in the location of my choosing.